# ko.bindingHandlers.validationCore.init doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I am trying to a custom binding to input as datepicker: 
CODE HERE: http://sdrv.ms/Xc5HZw

I have the following code in place but the validation doesn't highlight the control when its invalid:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
           // code here

          ko.bindingHandlers.validationCore.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor);


        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {

           // code here
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar problem... the minute i add ko.validation.js
both the init: function and update are skipped over.... nothing inside the function fires....

are you at least hitting the ko.bindingHandlers.validationCore method?